# Adding commas for string of lists python (doesn't work not duplicate)

Tags: python, string, list, join

So let's say I have a list of strings, that looks like this:

```
[["['item1','item2', 'item3']['item4', 'item5', 'item6']['item7','item8','item9']"]]
```

How do I separate the tiny lists by commas?

I want to eventually separate a huge text file that has list of lists that look like this by sorting  them based on one value for which I want to try this:

```
with open("sample.txt", "rU") as f:
    lines = [line for line in f.readlines()]

for group, items in itertools.groupby(lines[1:], lambda x: round(float(x.split()[-24]))):
    with open('group_%s' % group, 'w') as o:
        o.writelines(items)
```

But this won't work unless there are commas to separate the nested lists for which I tried this:

```
f = ",".join([str(x) for x in f])
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Where is your code? Can you format your example a little better?

Comment: Also, thats not a list of strings, thats a list that contains a list that contains a single string. Very big difference to a list of strings.

Comment: I'm trying to sort this super huge text file that has such lists, based on one value by doing the following: with open(“173.076-30.309.txt", "rU") as f:
    lines = [line for line in f.readlines()]

for group, items in itertools.groupby(lines[1:], lambda x: round(float(x.split()[-24]))):
    with open('group_%s' % group, 'w') as o:
        o.writelines(items)

Comment: Can you **edit** your question to include that code. Indenting is really important in Python.

Comment: but it won't work without the commas separating the lists so I've tried this stuff: list = ",".join([str(x) for x in list])

Comment: @AryaIyer What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant you have this string...

```
s = "['item1','item2', 'item3']['item4', 'item5', 'item6']['item7','item8','item9']"
```

then you can use the re module

```
import re

list_of_lists = []

ls = re.findall(r"\[.*?\]",s)
for l in ls:
    print l
    list_of_lists.append(eval(l))

"""
---Outputs---
['item1','item2', 'item3']
['item4', 'item5', 'item6']
['item7','item8','item9']
"""
```

you could then eval the string into a list...

Comment: the find all line gives an error TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Maybe you are passing a list for the second parameter?  It should be a string.  You can loop through your list and pass the strings one-by-one.

Comment: Before trying to call the findall method try doing print type(s) to find out what kind of variable your are working with.  That method requires a string.